# Making a batch file to zip contents of a folder in seperate zips

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need a batch file to zip the contents of the current directory into individual zip files (each file has its own zip file).  I'm interested in learning more about making batch files so help in breaking down what the script means would be appreciated.  Below is a batch to zip subdirectories in the current directory, I was going to try to edit it to zip individual files of a directory but I don't really know how to and I can't find a reference sheet or anything.  So if you have a link for something similar that would be great.

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\"
```

What I think I understand here is:
'for /d' will loop the batch through the directory
'in (*)' is designating the current directory
'do "executable location"' is designating the process
'a "%%X.zip"' is designating the file type?
I don't really understand what "%%X" is

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `FOR /D` is iterating all the folder names within the current working directory.  It assigns the directory name to the designated token of `%%X`.  Open up a command prompt and type: `FOR /?` to read the help file for the `FOR` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change what you have from zipping subfolders to zipping files, just remove the `/d`, then it will look for files instead of directories.

```
for %%X in (*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X"
```

To answer your question about what `%%X` is:  That's the variable.  When you go into the loop using for, you need some variable to represent whatever it is you're looping through.

As you go through the loop, `%%X` represents whatever file you're working on.
So if the first file was `File1.txt`, then the first time through the loop, `%%X` would equal `File1.txt`.

So the command would be: `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "File1.txt.zip" "File1.txt"`
Which if I recall the 7-zip arguments, you're saying add `File.txt` to a zip file named `File1.txt.zip`.  The next time through the loop, `%%X` represents the next file name.

By the way, if you're running this in the CLI ('command prompt' essentially), then you'd use a single %, for batch files you have to use two (%%).